# Drawing a circle that scales up based on device size opencv?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am able to draw a circle on the camera frame using the OpenCV circle method. Now, here is the thing, I want to make sure that the circle scales up based on different android device screen sizes. How do I go about it ?
This is what I tried so far.

```
 @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mrgba = inputFrame.rgba();
       // Imgproc.cvtColor(mrgba,mgray,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
       // Imgproc.Canny(mgray,mcanny,50,150);

        Imgproc.circle (
                mrgba,                 //Matrix obj of the image
                new Point(230, 160),    //Center of the circle
                100,                    //Radius
                new Scalar(0, 0, 255),  //Scalar object for color
                10                      //Thickness of the circle
        );

        return mrgba;
    }
```

Comment: Make your radius proportional to the minimum among width and height. Also make the thickness proportional to the radius. The center should be... in the center of your display? If so: `width * .5, height * .5` (multiplying by the inverse is faster than dividing).

Answer (score 0):

[Bernoulli Gate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649012/bernoulli-gate) is right with his comment. And you should take into in account not dimensions (in pixels or dp) of `JavaCameraView`, but dimensions of Camera Preview, because `Camera` can't return preview of any width/height (e.g. only "standard" resolution like `640x480` or `1024x768`, not `550x20`) and OpenCV `Mat` object `CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame.rgba();` dimensions in "OpenCV Mat pixels" equals dimensions of Camera Preview , not `JavaCameraView` (there are black stripes on "non Camera Preview" part of `JavaCameraView`). There are not so many "standard" resolutions of `Camera` and you can get all of it by this way (actually, that methods are deprecated and you should use `Camera2` approach, but they are still working now and IMHO more simple):

```
Camera mCamera;

mCamera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
for (Camera.Size size :sizes) {
    Log.d(TAG, "size: " + size.width + "x" + size.height);
}
```

and than in your app you can analyze max possible dimensions of Camera Preview and directly set your circle settings for each Camera Preview resolution. Something like that:

```
@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    if (width == 1920 && height == 1080) {
        circleRadius = 300; circleLineWidth = 20;
    } else if (width == 1280 && height == 720) {
        circleRadius = 275; circleLineWidth = 18;
    } else if (width == 1024 && height == 768) {
        circleRadius = 250; circleLineWidth = 15;
    } else if 
        ...
    } else {
        circleRadius = some_default_radius; circleLineWidth = some_default_width;
    }

}
```

also, you can prevent using higher then e.g. `1920x1080` resolution by call:

```
mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(1920, 1080);
```

after `mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);` and before `mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();` calls. Also you can set any values in `setMaxFrameSize()`, but Camera Preview in that case will be selected as nearest (for min dimension) "standard" resolution e.g. `320x240` for `mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(960, 250);` call.